# Db2 Timestamp format error while loading data into the table

Tags: db2, db2-luw

I am trying to load data into the table by this command below

```
LOAD CLIENT FROM 'C:\database_extract\budget1.csv' OF DEL MODIFIED BY USEDEFAULTS 
 MESSAGES 'C:\database_extract\budget1.log' REPLACE INTO CLP.budget
 NONRECOVERABLE INDEXING MODE AUTOSELECT;
```

I am getting the below error,

```
SQL0180N  The syntax of the string representation of a datetime value is incorrect. 
          SQLSTATE=22007
```

I have given the column datatype as TIMESTAMP date format in datasource is `11/1/2012 0:00`
Anyone Please help me to resolve the issue.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the following `MODIFIED BY` clause:

```
MODIFIED BY USEDEFAULTS TIMESTAMPFORMAT="M/D/YYYY H:MM"
```

See https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0008305.html for details on the `LOAD` command.

Comment: Thanks for Your quick reply

Comment: I tried the comment below

LOAD CLIENT FROM 'C:\database_extract\budget1.csv' OF DEL MODIFIED BY  timestampformat="dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm tt"
MESSAGES 'C:\database_extract\budget1.log' REPLACE INTO CLP.budget
NONRECOVERABLE INDEXING MODE AUTOSELECT;
SQL3191N  The field in row "F3-1", column "6" which begins with "3/1/2014 
0:00" does not match the user specified DATEFORMAT, TIMEFORMAT, or 
TIMESTAMPFORMAT. The row will be rejected.

Comment: I am getting this error        :SQL3191N  The field in row "F0-1", column "6" which begins with "11/1/2012 
0:00" does not match the user specified DATEFORMAT, TIMEFORMAT, or 
TIMESTAMPFORMAT. The row will be rejected.

Comment: I used this command : LOAD CLIENT FROM 'C:\database_extract\budget1.csv' OF DEL MODIFIED BY  timestampformat="mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt"
MESSAGES 'C:\database_extract\budget1.log' REPLACE INTO CLP.budget
NONRECOVERABLE INDEXING MODE AUTOSELECT;